# Is there a way to automatically generate a graph with a specific number of cycles?

Tags: graph, graph-theory

Is there a way to input a certain number and an algorithm create the graph with that specified number of cycles(undirected graph)?

I've found algorithms for generating graphs with a degree sequence of nodes and for generating graphs using a ranking and probabilstic approach to add probalities for certain edges to be formed(this one can encourage cycles but not too much control). Can't seem to find a model that can more accurately control the number of cycles in the graph and was just wondering whether it was possible.
[Degree sequence of nodes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0312028.pdf)
[Ranking and probabilistic approach](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.05274.pdf)

Comment: By loops you mean cycles?  Directed or undirected graph?  If N cycles are requested, then the trivial method would be to create N groups of 3 vertices and connect each group of nodes in a cycle.  I assume you want something more elaborate than that, but you will have to specify in more detail

Comment: A simple graph created so as to contain three "loops" https://imgur.com/a/iUROUm7